# i want to know how can I create data frame with existing data in r

Tags: r, dataframe

how can I create a new data frame as **df1** from **data1**  by choosing 6 columns in RStudio

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? It's nice for questions to show that some effort went in before asking.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- data1[, c("col_name_1", "col_name_2", "col_name_3", "col_name_4", "col_name_5", "col_name_6")]
```